# Polybase EXTERNAL TABLE access failed - permission denied

Tags: sql, sql-server

I`m trying to connect to hadoop via polybase in sql server 2016. 
My code is:

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyHadoopCluster WITH (  
      TYPE = HADOOP,   
       LOCATION ='hdfs://192.168.114.20:8020', 
       credential= HadoopUser1  
      );  


CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT TextFileFormat WITH (  
        FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT,   
     FORMAT_OPTIONS (FIELD_TERMINATOR ='\001',   
             USE_TYPE_DEFAULT = TRUE)
);


CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[test_hadoop] (  
        [Market_Name] int NOT NULL,   
        [Claim_GID] int NOT NULL,   
        [Completion_Flag] int NULL,   
        [Diag_CDE] float NOT NULL,   
        [Patient_GID] int NOT NULL, 
        [Record_ID] int NOT NULL, 
        [SRVC_FROM_DTE] int NOT NULL  
)  
WITH (LOCATION='/applications/gidr/processing/lnd/sha/clm/cf/claim_diagnosis',   
        DATA_SOURCE = MyHadoopCluster,  
        FILE_FORMAT = TextFileFormat

);
```

And i got this error:

> EXTERNAL TABLE access failed due to internal error: 'Java exception
>   raised on call to HdfsBridge_GetDirectoryFiles: Error [Permission
>   denied: user=pdw_user, access=READ_EXECUTE,
>   inode="/applications/gidr/processing/lnd/sha/clm/cf/claim_diagnosis":root:supergroup:drwxrwxr--
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkFsPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:281)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.check(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:262)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:152)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6590)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6572)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPathAccess(FSNamesystem.java:6497)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getListingInt(FSNamesystem.java:5034)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getListing(FSNamesystem.java:4995)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getListing(NameNodeRpcServer.java:882)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.getListing(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:335)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getListing(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:615)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:617)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1073)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2086)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2082)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2080) ]
>   occurred while accessing external file.'

The problem is, in newest version of polybase there is no config file, in which you can specify hadoop default login and password. So even, when i`m creating scoped credentials, polybase is still using default pdw_user. I even tried to create pdw_user on hadoop, but still got this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Kerberos secured Hadoop cluster, make sure you alter the xml files as described https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/polybase-configuration

If it is not a Kerberos secured Hadoop cluster, make sure that the default user pdw_user has read access to hdfs and execute permissions on Hive.

Comment: Can you expand on the link, and summarize the contents?